# Stack overflow error when the range of numbers is over 40

Tags: c++, runtime-error, overflow

the program is supposed to prompt for a range of numbers then spit out the juggler sequence for the numbers in the range but whenever i enter a range over 40 i get a stack overflow error not sure why thanks
"Unhandled exception at 0x77354A3E (ntdll.dll) in juggler_seq.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00092FF4)."

// juggler_seq.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
template <typename T>

std::string to_string(T value){
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << value;
    return os.str();
}

std::string jugglers(long int n, std::string ans = ""){
    std::string num;
    if (n == 1){
        //checks for base case if 1 returns the seqence of numbers
        return ans + "1";
    }
    else{
        //checks for even odd
        if (n % 2 == 0){
            ans = ans + to_string(n) + ",";
            //ans now adjusted to include most recent number calculated in the sequence
            return jugglers(long int(pow(n, (1.0 / 2.0))), ans);
            //passes the most recent number into the funtion again until the sequence converges to 1
            //also passes the string ans with all previous numbers in sequence to keep track of numbers in the sequence
        }
        else{
            num = to_string(n);
            ans = ans + to_string(n) + ",";
            return jugglers(long int(pow(n, (3.0 / 2.0))), ans);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int s, e;
    int high = 0;
    std::string usrstr;
    std::list<std::string> ans;
    std::list<std::string>::iterator it;
    std::string n;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::cout << "whats the starting point: ";
    getline(std::cin, usrstr);
    std::stringstream(usrstr) >> s;
    std::cout << "\nwhats the end point: ";
    getline(std::cin, usrstr);
    std::stringstream(usrstr) >> e;
    for (long int y = s; y != e + 1;y++){

        ans.push_back(jugglers(y));
    }
    std::string com = "";
    int count = 0;
    int ref = 0;
    for (it = ans.begin(); it != ans.end(); it++){
        std::cout << *it<<std::endl;
        std::string a = *it;
        if (a.size()>com.size()){
            com = a;
            ref = count;
        }
        count += 1;

    }
    std::cout << "the ref is: " << ref + s << " the answer is : " << com << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually a stack overflow is caused by going off the end of an array or doing too many recursive calls.  Your first step is to use either the built-in debugger or maybe gdb to slowly, painfully, step your way through your own code and find out where it is happening and why. :-)  Have fun!  This is what programming is all about.  Well, having a cool program also helps.  But finding those bugs can be a lot of fun too. :-)

Comment: Use your favorite debugger to step through the code and check a) whether everything is working correctly and b) whether the recursion depth gets big and c) whether `n` gets big.

Comment: You are recursively calling with `n^1/2` for even numbers and with `n^3/2` for odd numbers. Is there any reason why they won't flip flop between odd and even numbers until the stack overflows?

Comment: The [juggler sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juggler_sequence) can result in some very large numbers. For example, starting with 37, the largest value reached is 24906114455136. So as minimum, a `long` on your  system needs to be 64-bits. Even then I don't think that using `pow` is going to work, since a `double` only has about 16 digits of precision.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. Syntax.

   ```
   return jugglers(long int(pow(n, (1.0 / 2.0))), ans);
   ```

   should be a compiler error. The correct method is:

   ```
   return jugglers((long int)(pow(n, (1.0 / 2.0))), ans);
   ```

   or, better still,

   ```
   return jugglers(static_cast<long int>(pow(n, (1.0 / 2.0))), ans);
   ```

   Same problem exists in the line

   ```
   return jugglers(long int(pow(n, (3.0 / 2.0))), ans);
   ```
2. Integer overflow

   When the number returned by the call to `pow` becomes to large to fit in a `long int`, next call to `pow` results in an error. In my test environment, the number 163 caused that problem. At some point the value of `n` reached `-9223372036854775808` and stayed there, causing stack overflow. That is eerily close to `LONG_MIN`, `-9223372036854775807`.
3. I don't see any reason why the `n` won't flip flob between an odd number and even number. That would cause a stack overflow too. In the previous case, the value of `n` kept increasing due to a sequence of odd numbers.

I was able to get the program to terminate by changing the argument type to `unsigned long` and changing the first check to:

```
if (n <= 1){
```

However, that's just a hack. When the `n` got to the point of integer overflow, any subsequent code is subject to undefined behavior.

In my test case, the output for `163` was:

```
163,2081,94931,29249071,158186025767,62914706160224992,250828041,3972502044577,7917648072381635584,2813831564,53045,12217059,42702176063,8824193242915619,1
```

As you can see from the output, the termination was rather abrupt not logical.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok.  The problem comes from long integer overflow.

I tested it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/5PgDlk) with some additional display:  with n until 36 there is a convergence of your recursive function.  With 37,  you overflow the maximum value a long int can hold.  Your recursivity is then broken, without convergence, which triggers a stack overflow.

If you use `long long` it will work (until the next capcity overflow):

```
std::string jugglers(long long int n, std::string ans = ""){
    ...
        return jugglers((long long int)(pow(n, (1.0 / 2.0))), ans);
    ...
        return jugglers((long long int)(pow(n, (3.0 / 2.0))), ans);
}
```

**Preventing the numeric overflow to cause a stack overflow:**

If you want to make it more robust, you could try to anticipate the overflow:

- On the even branch of `jugglers()`, you'll make recursive calls with a smaller number (because raising power to 1/2 means the square root, and here n>1). So nothing bad could happend.
- On the odd branch, you'll make a recursive call with a bigger number than n.  If there's an integer overflow chances are that raising ot the power of 3/2 will compute a number that is smaller than the current one.  It's easy to monitor this situation and stop with an error message:

  ```
      ... 
      long long int r = (long long int)(pow(n, (3.0 / 2.0)));
      if (r>n)
          return jugglers(r, ans);
      else {
          std::cout<< "Integer overflow at "<<n<<std::endl; 
          return ""; 
      }
      ...
  ```

THis approach works here, but is not so clean, as you do an operation which causes the numeric overflow and detect it afterwards.

The alternative would be to check if n causes problem before raising the power:

```
       if (n>pow(std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max(), 2.0/3.0)) {
            std::cout<<std::endl<<"Fatal error for "<<n<<std::endl; 
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: @user3386109 interesting remark. Nevertheless, you assume IEC559 encoding.  You should rather avoid hard-coded numbers and prefer `(1<<numeric_limits<double>::digits)` (see [here](http://ideone.com/MoN84R)).  Note also that bigger integers can be represented without loss, if they are powers of 2 (but that can't be the case in this branch of code dedicated to odd numbers ;-) ).